# Xamarin Visual Studio projects takes long time to build and launch in simulator

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios

I have:

**1.** Downloaded Xamarin plugin for Visual Studio 2015 on my Windows 7PC with 16GB RAM.

**2.** Installed Xamarin studio on my 2009 MacBook (2GB RAM) running the latest El Capitan OS.

I am running some of the sample template iOS projects offered by Visual Studio and getting them to launch on my Mac.

I have noticed that each project takes several minutes to build and sometimes up to 5 minutes to launch in the simulator.

Is this down to my old (And slow Mac book) or is this typical of the speeds of Xamarin in Visual Studio?

Comment: I would suspect this is due to a 7 year old mac book. A sample project really shouldn't take longer than a minute or so at maximum.

Comment: I would "assume" it is the 2GB of ram on that MacBook as the Core2Duo is not that bad, not great by todays standards, but... Those '09 models officially support 4gb, but you can actually get 6gb into it (4gb+2gb module).  Run `Activity Manager` on that Mac while you are compiling/debugging an iOS app and watch the memory tab to see what the memory pressure looks like.....

Comment: Activity Monitor indicates: Physical Memory: 2.00 GB and Memory Used: 1.71 GB.  It took 3 1/2 minutes to launch the Tabbed App template project. I contacted my local mac repair store and they said the model of Mac I have can actually support 8GB RAM - Is it worth going for this ? or will it still suck when running Xamarin?

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded the RAM from 2GB to 8GB and now most of the sample template projects launch in approx 20 seconds. HAPPY DAYS :) :)

Answer (score 1):

The SDK emulator is very slow and has many issues . I would recommend you to use Genymotion as it is more faster and light and your visual studio will detect it once launched.

you can install the free version for this link https://www.genymotion.com/